# Sum of two gamma/Erlang random variables $\Gamma(m,\lambda)$ and $\Gamma(n, \mu)$ with integer numbers $m \neq n, \lambda \neq \mu$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

The gamma distribution with parameters $m > 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ (denoted $\Gamma(m, \lambda)$) has density function
$$f(x) = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda x)^{m - 1}}{\Gamma(m)}, x > 0$$
Given two independent gamma random variables $X = \Gamma(m,\lambda)$ and $Y = \Gamma(n, \mu)$ with integer numbers $m \neq n, \lambda \neq \mu$, what is the density function of their sum $X + Y = \Gamma(m,\lambda) + \Gamma(n,\mu)$?

Notice that both $X$ and $Y$ are also [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) since $m,n$ are positive integers.

**My attempt**

First, I searched for well-known results about gamma distribution and I got:

(1) If $\lambda = \mu$, the sum random variable is a Gamma distribution $\sim \Gamma(m+n, \lambda)$ (See [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/250059/51434)).

(2) $\Gamma(m, \lambda)$ (or $\Gamma(n, \mu)$) is the sum of $m$ (or $n$) independent exponential random variables each having rate $\lambda$ (or $\mu$). The [hypoexponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution) is related to the sum of independent exponential random variables. However, it require all the rates *distinct*.

(3) [This site](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/%7Efmassey/gammaRV/) is devoted to the problem of **sums of gamma random variables**. In section 3.1, it claims that if $m$ and $n$ are integer numbers (which **is** my case), the density  function **can** be expressed in terms of elementary functions (proved in section 3.4). *The answer is likely buried under a haystack of formulas (however, I failed to find it; you are recommended to have a try)*.

Then, I try to calculate it:

$$f_{X+Y}(a) = \int_{0}^{a} f_{X}(a-y) f_{Y}(y) dy \\ = \int_{0}^{a} \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda (a-y)} (\lambda (a-y))^{m-1}}{\Gamma(m)} \frac{\mu e^{-\mu y} (\mu y)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} dy \\ = e^{-\lambda a} \frac{\lambda^m \mu^n}{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^{a} e^{(\lambda - \mu) y} (a-y)^{m-1} y^{n-1} dy$$

Here, I am stuck with the integral and gain nothing ... Therefore,

> 1. How to compute the density function of $\Gamma(m,\lambda) + \Gamma(n,\mu)$ with integer numbers $m \neq n, \lambda \neq \mu$?
> 2. **Added:** The answers assuming $m = n$ ($\lambda \neq \mu$) are also appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I had missed (a quite crucial) parenthesis! Will try to have a closer look later instead.

Comment: @hejseb Thank you all the same. And you are recommended to refer to the [material: Sums of Gamma Random Variables](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~fmassey/gammaRV/) mentioned in the post if you want to come back. The answer is likely buried under a haystack of formulas (however, I failed to find it).

Comment: You are almost there.  Since $m$ and $n$ are integers, expand $(a-y)^{m-1}y^{n-1}$ via the binomial theorem into a polynomial in $y$. Then you are left with a sum of integrals of the form $\displaystyle \int_0^a y^ie^{\nu y}\, dy$ each of which can be integrated by parts.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Following your instruction, I get the integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{a} e^{(\lambda - \mu) y} y^{n+x-1} dy$. Here $x$ is related to the general term of binomial extension of $(a-y)^{m-1}$ . Using [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB+e%5E%28%7B%CE%BB-%CE%BC%7Dy%29+%28y%5E%7Bn%2Bx-1%7D%29+dy), I get the Gamma distribution (i.e., $\Gamma(n+x, \mu - \lambda)$) back. In addition, I find it hard to combine the binomial terms together after computing the integrals. Stuck again...

Comment: @DilipSarwate This problem actually arises from a Renewal process. I have done some calculation and come at the sum of two gamma random variables presented in this post. It is likely that I am taking a detour. I will think over my original problem. Thanks.

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Statistics);
X := RandomVariable(GammaDistribution(m, lambda)):
Y := RandomVariable(GammaDistribution(n, mu)):
PDF(X+Y, t)\, assuming\, m::posint, n::posint, m <> n; $$ produces the answer in terms of [LaguerreL](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LaguerreL).

Comment: @user64494 It is helpful. Thanks. If it is hard to get a closed formula, I will consider its numerical solution following your code. By the way, will the other assumption that **integer** numbers $\lambda \neq \mu$ lead to an alternate (maybe simpler) form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closed form expression is provided in the following paper.

SV Amari, RB Misra, Closed-form expressions for distribution of sum of exponential random variables, IEEE Transactions on Reliability, 46 (4), 519-522.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

We summarize the development in follows:

Step 1: We simplify the case to be $l(\Gamma(m, 1)+k\Gamma(n,1))$ by choosing appropriate $k,l$ for a scale transformation.

Step 2. We want to calculate
$$
\Gamma(m,1)+k\Gamma(n,1)=\sum^{m}_{i=1}X_{i}+k\sum^{n}_{i=1}Y_{j}
$$

Step 3. For $m=n$ case, we only need to calculate $X+kY$, where $X,Y\sim \Gamma(1,1)$. In the case of $k=1$, we let
$$
Z=X+Y,W=\frac{X}{X+Y}, X=ZW, Y=Z-ZW
$$
The Jacobian is $Z$. Therefore we have
$$
f_{Z,W}(z,w)=ze^{-zw}e^{zw-z}dzdw=ze^{-z}dzdw
$$
and $$
Z\sim \Gamma(2,1)
$$
as desired. In the general case we have
$$
Z=X+kY, W=\frac{X}{X+kY}, X=ZW, Y=\frac{1}{k}(Z-ZW)
$$
The Jacobian is $\frac{1}{k}Z$. We thus have
$$
f_{Z,W}(z,w)=\frac{1}{k}ze^{-zw}e^{\frac{1}{k}(zw-z)}=\frac{1}{k}ze^{-\frac{k-1}{k}zw-\frac{1}{k}z}
$$
and I do not have a good way to factorize it.

A reason this technique might not work in general is the moment generating function does not change when we use the scale transformation, and for different $\beta$ the moment generating function is different. Thus the problem may be better to be attacked numerically.

Comment: As you suggest, the computation of the density function of $X + Y$ can be reduced to that of $X' + kY''$. However, why is $X', Y'' \sim \text{exp}(1)$? In my calculation, it is of form $\sim \Gamma(n, 1) = \frac{e^{-x} x^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} = \frac{e^{-x} x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ since $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: I updated the computation. I think you are right, the factorization now seems rather complicated.

Comment: I think I found a way out.

Comment: Some constants may still be off, I need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. The factorization trick is rather impressive. However, it seems that you have missed the requirement that $m \neq n$. Following your instruction, I get: $$X + Y = \lambda \Gamma(m,1) + \mu \Gamma(n,1) = \lambda (\Gamma(m,1) + \frac{\mu}{\lambda} \Gamma(n,1)) = \lambda (\sum_{i=1}^{m} \text{exp}(1) + \frac{\mu}{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{exp}(1))$$. Unfortunately, we cannot factor $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}$ out and focus on $$\text{exp}(1) + \frac{\mu}{\lambda} \text{exp}(1)$$. What do you think of it? (Now it has been reduced to the *weighted sum* of $\text{exp}(1)$s).

Comment: By my previous calculations, if $m,n$ are different then the result is messy. I do not see a clear way out. The same trick applies, but the result is not "impressive" anymore as I cannot factorize it.

Comment: Thanks. Your result $$exp(1) + k exp(1) \sim \Gamma(1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2k})$$ is useful. Some other distributions than Gamma or Erlang, e.g., [Hyper-exponential (weighted sum of exponentials)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperexponential_distribution) and [Hypoexponential (general sum of exponentials)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution) may be useful too. And, I believe, the answer (not likely in a neat formula) is hidden in [site: Sums of Gamma Random Variables](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~fmassey/gammaRV/), although I failed to find it.

Comment: A little question: In the calculation of the probability density function of $X_i + k Y_i$, how to get the constant $(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4k^2})$? I only obtain $\frac{1}{2k}$ which is $|J(X_i, Y_i)|^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant "some constants may still be off". By kernel method I should get $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4k^{2}}$, but direct calculation showed it to be $\frac{1}{2k}$. I was puzzled by it as well. I thought it is most likely to be a computation mistake on my side.

Comment: Does it mean that the intermediate conclusion that it is a Gamma random variable is debatable?

Comment: The factorization should still hold, so it must be a Gamma distribution . But I am not entirely sure what was wrong with the constants. For example, if $k=1$, then the result I give obviously would not make sense. This means the whole result may be wrong.

Comment: For $k=1$, I am expecting $X_{i}+Y_{i}=\Gamma(1,1)+\Gamma(1,1)\sim \Gamma(2,1)$, and so is $X_{i}-Y_{i}$. But the result obviously mismatches.

Comment: To the specific problem, we may get stumped and frustrated. Generally, your efforts and attention are invaluable to me.

Comment: I am quite embarrassed (as you can tell), for I will be the TA for probability class next semester. Allow me sometime to think about this carefully.

Comment: It would be OK to make mistakes on calculation (and really, who doesn't?). I am asking for help and you have helped me a lot. Hope that it will not upset you too much.

Comment: Updated, but the result is still not good enough. It turns out the mistake with the constants is because of follows: $X-Y$'s range may no longer be in $[0,\infty)$. Therefore one has to integrate over $(-\infty, \infty)$ instead, and the integral would not converge. Here I used a scale transformation for $W$ instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have posted a related problem at [MO site](http://mathoverflow.net/q/168089/28199) and got some references which concern *the sum of Gamma distributions*: `P. G. Moschopoulos (1985) The distribution of the sum of independent gamma random variables, Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics, 37, 541-544` and `A. M. Mathai (1982) Storage capacity of a dam with gamma type inputs, Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics, 34, 591-597`. They use moment generating functions too. As you suggested, I am considering its numerical solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: I checked the first paper, which is in the author's webpage. It seems he used some ingenious algebraic identities to deduce the pdf from the mgf. The notation is a bit hard to read and there are no examples. But hopefully this solved the problem to some extent.

Comment: I have got another answer [from MO site](http://mathoverflow.net/a/168240/28199). However, it is beyond my current knowledge. Would you mind reviewing it at your convenience? Thanks.

Comment: I read it briefly. The first part is clear, but I am slightly lost with the second part. I think since the probability $P(A<L<B)$ is assumed to be a constant, taking expectation of it should be itself. The first part comes from computation $P(L\le A)$ and $P(L\le B)$, then take the difference. The second part then take expectation of the two numbers with respect to $L$. Since $L\sim \exp(\lambda)$, its pdf is of the form $e^{-\lambda x}dx$(in some conventions). Therefore the expectation with respect to $L$ is a function of $\lambda$, namely $P(A\le L)$'s Laplace transform.

Comment: For the last step we use the fact that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$, here we may let $X_{i}=\lambda (S_{i}+A_{i})$. Then we only need to calculate the term $E(e^{-p(S_i+A_i)})$, which he/she gave a hint on the final result. I do not have time to check the details, but I think he/she probably did the computation by hand and get this formula.

Comment: I have to say this is amazing work (if it is correct).

Comment: Yes, it is amazing. It avoids the messy calculation of convolution of two Gamma random variables. Thanks for your efforts. I will investigate it further.

Comment: My only bit of misunderstanding is I do not see where he used the fact $S_{i},A_{i}$ are random variables instead of scalars. Perhaps this is done in the last step using the identity $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$ or something similar. Otherwise computing it involves some kind of simple double integral. I assume he/she must have calculated it. The only way to verify it is to compute this once ourselves.

Comment: A comment comes from the author of the amazing solution at [MO site](http://mathoverflow.net/a/168240/28199). You can make comments at the MO site if you will. This Math.SE site is always "complaining about" the comments which go longer and longer.

Answer (score 0):

see eqn 3.383(1) of book [tables of integrals Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://www.vixri.com/d/Gradshtejn,%20Ryzhikov_Tablicy%20Integralov.pdf), it reads

> $$\int\limits_0^u x^{\nu-1}(u-x)^{\mu-1}e^{\beta x}\,\mathrm{d}x=
> B(\mu,\nu)\overline{u}^{\mu+\nu-1} {}_1F_1(\nu;\mu+\nu;\beta u)\\
> [\operatorname{Re}\mu>0,\,\operatorname{Re}\nu>0].$$